# Grails 3 with Spring boot autoconfigure

Tags: grails, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate a Grails application with the Netflix Eureka stuff for using Spring Cloud Ribbon for making REST calls to services. In a normal Spring Boot application it is nothing more than adding the required dependencies and the spring boot autoconfigure will make sure that my RestTemplate is configured for the Ribbon use.

But in our Grails (3.0.7) application the Spring Boot autoconfiguration will not kick in. Does anyone have an idea to get the Grails with Spring Boot autoconfigure working?

Comment: either setup your your stuff in the resource.groovy or add an @ComponentScan("packagename") on your Application

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Spring boot's `@AutoConfigure` was working after all.

Problem when trying to use a Spring `RestTemplate` for rest with Ribbon:

```
class MyController {

    RestTemplate restTemplate

    def index() {
        def result = restTemplate.getEntity("http://my-service/whatever", Void.class) // call gives nullPointerException due restTemplate is not injected
        render "Response: $result"
    }
}
```

Because Spring Boot registers the Ribbon enabled `RestTemplate` bean not under bean name `restTemplate`, the Grails convention based injection mechanism (field name must match bean name) doesn't work. To work around this problem it is needed to `@Autowired` to the `restTemplate` field and let Spring do the injection.

So this is the solution:

```
class MyController {

    @AutoWired
    RestTemplate restTemplate

    def index() {
        def result = restTemplate.getEntity("http://my-service/whatever", Void.class) // restTemplate is now injected using Spring instead of Grails
        render "Response: $result"
    }
}
```